# PHP issue, forward slash showing on some pages but not others

Tags: php

I've got a php echo which I'm using to echo out image banners on a zen cart based system.

```
<hgroup id="cat_banner" style="background-image:url(images/categories/banners<?php echo"/"; echo strtolower(str_replace('&','and',str_replace(' ','_',$breadcrumb->last()))); ?>_banner.jpg);">

<h1 id="productListHeading"><?php echo $breadcrumb->last(); ?></h1>
<?php

// categories_description

    if ($current_categories_description != '') {

?>

<p id="indexProductListCatDescription" class="content"><?php echo $current_categories_description;  ?></p>

<?php } // categories_description ?>
```

it is not showing the / on some images but is showing it on others and displaying the image.

Comment: Sorry the code hasn't added correctly.                                                 <hgroup id="cat_banner" style="background-image:url(images/categories/banners<?php echo"/"; echo strtolower(str_replace('&','and',str_replace(' ','_',$breadcrumb->last()))); ?>_banner.jpg);">

Comment: why do you echo that forward slash instead of hard coding it?

Comment: I did hard code it, I changed it to try different things to see if it would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = strtolower(str_replace('&','and',str_replace(' ','_',$breadcrumb->last())));
<hgroup id="cat_banner" style="background-image:url("images/categories/banners/".$path."_banner.jpg)>
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately, it was adding spaces between the link where the slashes should be.